# PHP SQL / Duplicate entries

Tags: sql

I have a sql database and i don´t know, how to solve the following problem. For example - the database looks like this

Col A | Col B | Col C

It should be possible that Col A has some dublicate entries / Col B has some duplicate entries - but it should not be possible that the pair of Col A & B can be listed twice. How do i have to prepare the database and insert statement.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (You've already got one product specific answer.)

Comment: Well the best way to guarantee that is tu put an UNIQUE constraint on your pair of column

Comment: The idea you are searching for is known as "composite key".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a unique index on Col A and Col B:

MySQL:

```
ALTER TABLE `mytable` ADD UNIQUE `unique_index`(`ColA`, `ColB`);
```

ANSI SQL example:

```
ALTER TABLE mytable ADD CONSTRAINT unique_index UNIQUE (ColA,ColB);
```

Comment: Will work well as long as OP uses MySQL. The general ANSI SQL syntax is slightly different.

Comment: @jarlh Thanks hadn't noticed user didn't tag MySQL. Added the ANSI SQL example too.